# How can I scrape text using selenium by class? Error message: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to write a program that scrapes the info about a stock from Yahoo finance using selenium on python. But I keep getting this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

I would find by ID, but there is no id in that part of the html, I have included a photo for reference. There is mostly only just classes. I have tried many classes from the html, but all of them give me the same error. I don't think it's because it hasn't loaded because I put a time.sleep beforehand to ensure it loads in. If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'yfin-usr-qry')))
    input1 = browser.find_element_by_id('yfin-usr-qry')
    input1.send_keys(self.stockslist[0])
    input1.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
    stockinfo = browser.find_element_by_class_name('Mend(20px)')
    print(stockinfo.text)
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.quit()
```

[here is a link to the html of the text I am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dylnq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath` to select and extract text. Please refer the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/NIO?p=NIO&.tsrc=fin-srch')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Search element and print text
Stock_Price = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '(//div[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/descendant::span)[1]')))
print(Stock_Price.text)
```

Let me know if you have any query. Thanks

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. I noticed that the id 'quote-header-info' gives several lines of text, how did you make it only print out the stock price?

Comment: @AndyPeng You have to learn `xpath` navigation. If it resolve yours issue then please mark it as ans. Thanks.

Comment: Take help from this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uktjWgKrtI)